# how to select dropdown value which will be generated based on first dropdown selection using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

The webpage having two dropdowns, first dropdown will list country values and second dropdown will list cities of the country.

So second dropdown values will be generated based on country selected in first drop down.

how to handle this in selenium?

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help section to learn how to write a good question so that it's more likely to provide the info needed for others to help you. Please post the relevant HTML, the code you have tried, and what issue(s) you are having.

Comment: Please go through [ask]